# The correspondence between complex spin structures and associated clifford module structure

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, spin-geometry

The usual definition of a $spin^c$ structure on a riemannian manifold $M$ is often given by (the equivalence class of) the lifting of the frame bundle $P\to M$ of the tangent bundle $TM$ via the standard homomorphism $Spin^c(n)\to SO(n)$.

And there is yet another definition given in *Monopoles and Three-manifolds,* *Kronheimer and Mrowka*:

A $spin^c$ structure is a choice of "spinor bundle" $S$ (a complex vector bundle of proper dimension) and a Clifford multiplication $\rho : TM\to End(S)$ which satisfies $\rho(X)^2=-\left<X,X\right>id_{S}$ (hence extendable to the action of the Clifford algebra on $S$, $Cl(TM)\to End(S)$ which we furthermore assume that this restricts to the spin representation $Cl(T_xM)\to End(S_x)$ on each fiber).

(It might be the case that this definition is only valid in low-dimensional manifolds, especially 3 and 4Ds.)

Sadly this is where I stuck. After some searching, the equivalence between these two definitions is a forklore to experts, but it is hard to find the reference to the proof. My current understanding is,

1. From the first definition to the second, the correspondence is (should be?) via the associated bundle construction w.r.t. the standard $spin^c$ representation $Spin^c(n)\to End(\Delta)$. For this direction, I have no confusion, this is totally fine with me.
2. For the reverse direction, I have little clue. I only feel there would be a similar construction as "the frame bundle construction of a vector bundle that makes a correspondence between $SO(n)$-bundles and (oriented) vector bundles". But what can be a version of frames in the case of spinors?
3. Or it might be possible that we can directly show the bijectiveness of the correspondence from the first to the second. But, from the second definition, I feel there's more freedom than the first, say we can choose a trivial bundle of proper dimension as $S$ and then there's no obstruction in defining a Clifford multiplication map $TM\to End(S)$ (at least considering the fact that End(S) has much larger dimension than $TM$). So, in this approach, the bijective correspondence seems rather a miracle to me.

Comment: This is not the exact form of the definition. What really happens is that, given a choice of a metric on $M$, you have a bundle of Clifford algebras $Cl(TM) \to M$. There is a 2-category of $\mathbb Z/2$-graded associative algebras, where the objects are such algebras (in particular, Clifford algebras with their obvious grading) and the morphisms a bimodules between them (the 2-morphisms are morphisms of bimodules). You can consider $Cl(TM)$ as a functor from $M$ to this 2-category and the spin structure is the isomorphism between $Cl(TM)$ and the trivial functor $Cl(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: More specifically, you need to choose a $Cl(T_x M) - Cl(\mathbb{R}^n)$ bimodule smoothly depending on the point, i.e. a bundle with a left pointwise action of $Cl(TM)$ and a right pointwise action of $Cl(\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the standard euclidean space. But not any such bundle will suffice: it must be an isomorphism in the 2-category defined above, which means that (assuming $E$ is this spin bundle) we must have $E \otimes_{Cl(TM)} E \simeq Cl(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $E\otimes_{Cl(\mathbb{R}^n)} E \simeq Cl(TM)$ as bimodules.

Comment: For $spin^c$ structure you need to consider complex vector bundles, complexified tangent space $TM\otimes {\mathbb C}$ and complex Clifford algebras. The isomorphisms above mean that fiberwise $E$ is just $Cl(T_x M)\simeq Cl(\mathbb{R}^n)$, possibly up to a shift of grading.

Comment: @AntonFetisov Thanks for the comment. I guess what you have explained is the contents of [Plymen's paper](http://www.theta.ro/jot/archive/1986-016-002/1986-016-002-008.pdf). I'm not super familiar with such a category theoretic notion that you mentioned, but theorem 2.11 in this paper is readily understandable to me and basically tells us that an isomorphism between bundles of algebras $Cl(TM)$ or $Cl(TM)_0$(depending on the parity of the dimension of $M$) and $End(S)$ determines a complex spin structure, right?

Comment: More or less, yes. I guess that corresponds to the $E \otimes_{Cl(\mathbb{R}^n)} E^* = Cl(TM)$ line above. By the way, I forgot dualizations above, but can't edit it now.